# How to convert an ISO 8601 formatted date into a timestamp with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, timestamp

I have a time string in this format - `2015-09-17T16:00:00`. How do I convert it to a timestamp format like this - `1447804800000` using Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

```js
var x = new Date("2015-09-17T16:00:00").getTime();
alert(x);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: Just curious as why it gives different results in firefox and chrome. Try running this code - http://jsbin.com/liqoqozuhi/edit?html,console,output in both firefox and chrome.

Comment: @KematRochi so that is not a standard format. Try doing `new Date("2015-09-17T16:00:00.0Z").getTime();` and it will give same result in both the browsers.